# Remove recursion when sending variable as parameter to anonymous function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've encountered this before and I have a fair understanding of scope though not enough. I'm trying to pass a string as a parameter to an anonymous function, inside of a for loop. From my understanding by default this is recursive so no matter how many times the variable's string changes it still sends the same string (1,2,3,4 is passed on (maybe like?) 1,1,1,1 when we want 1,2,3,4).

I want to make this non-recursive so in the example below the file names from the multiple-file-input-element are different (since none of them can be the same).

How can we make the event listener receive the non-recursive parameter?

```
function images_upload(e)
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('post_files').files.length; i++)
 {
  var file = document.getElementById('post_files').files[i];
  var n = images_name(file.name);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (typeof xhr.upload=='object')
  {
   var upload = xhr.upload;
   upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e,n)
   {
    alert('n = '+n);
   }, false);
   xhr.open('POST','upload.php');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.name);
   xhr.send(file);
  }
  else {var ns = true;}
 }

 if (ns) {alert('Error: your browser does not support AJAX file uploads.');}
}
```

Yes, I know the context of what I'm testing (testing in Firefox 10, Chrome 17(?) and Opera 12).

Comment: why are you using `progress` event? Maybe you would use `readystatechange` event instead?

Comment: The readystatechange event is not relevant to my question. I really don't have the time to determine another way to reproduce the problem in even a remotely similar context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two snippets:

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
       // here, i will be the loop variable, and thus you'll get
       // an ouput of 5, 5 times, because by the time this function will be
       // called, the loop will be long finished
       console.log(i); 
    }, 250);
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        return function () {
           // here, i will be the function parameter of the outer function
           // which has been called immediately passing in a 'copy' of
           // the loop variable.
           // output will be: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
           console.log(i); 
        };
    }(i), 250);
}
​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpxqq/

Also, this has nothing to do with recursion.

---

Regarding your code, you should change:

```
upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e,n)
{
  alert('n = '+n);
}, false);
```

to:

```
upload.addEventListener('progress', function (n) {
  return function(e) {
    alert('n = ' + n);
  };
}(n), false);
```

Comment: Earlier I was going to comment that I've used setTimeout though I consider it cheap (negative connotation) instead of affordable (positive connotation); sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. The suggestion you made in your edit works in Chrome and Opera 12 though not Firefox 10.

Comment: @John the setTimeout was just to demonstrate an async. function call. The thing to note here is the scope of event callback function. If you check the demo-fiddle in ff you'll get the correct output. So I guess that there might be something else preventing your script from working in ff.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have block scope...

Try this :

```
function images_upload(e) {
    var ns = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('post_files').files.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var file = document.getElementById('post_files').files[i];
            var n = images_name(file.name);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if (typeof xhr.upload == 'object') {
                var upload = xhr.upload;
                upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e, n) {
                    alert('n = ' + n);
                }, false);
                xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', file.name);
                xhr.send(file);
            }
            else {
                ns = true;
            }

        })(i);
    }

    if (ns) {
        alert('Error: your browser does not support AJAX file uploads.');
    }
}
```